# Change Default site on wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite

I have a wordpress multi-site where I staged a "sandbox" site and I'm now ready to move this sandbox to the production site. I feel comfortable doing everything but for some reason the main site is un-editable.

The main site is "website.com"

The new site is "website.com/sandbox"

I basically want to change the main site to "website.com/old" and make the new site "website.com".

Any idea how to unlock the current main site so I can change the URL? I tried this already:

```
 define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2);
 define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2);
```

But that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

In order for sub-directory multi-site to work, it needs to modify the mod_rewrite rule (i.e. .htaccess file). Do you simply added the two lines in the wp_config.php or crated a WordPress network as described [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Network_Screen)?

Comment: I actually just had to make sure I only changed `define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2);` and not `define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2);`. Changing both of them is what caused the issue.